# Root folder change thru htacces

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to change the root folder of my site to a subfolder.

The site today is placed on /public_html, but I want to place it on /public_html/NEWFOLDER

To do it, I'm using htacces file with the following code

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com\.br$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com\.br$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !NEWFOLDER/
    RewriteRule (.*) /NEWFOLDER/$1 [L]
```

But it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteRule` is pointed to the root `/NEWFOLDER/ETC` and not `/public_html/NEWFOLDER/ETC`.

You might want to look the Apache's [RewriteBase](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) feature.